# Remove a row from a QStandardItemModel where selected row is a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, delete-row, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I have a Qt project where I have a `QStandardItemModel` called `stockModel`. This model is linked to a `QTableView` called `tvStock`.

I have a button called `btnDelete` which has a `clicked` event set up as follows:

```
void StockItems::on_btnDelete_clicked()
{
    //delete
}
```

How do I delete the selected row of `tvStock` from `stockModel`?

I assume I can start with this (but I'm not sure how to complete it):

```
stockModel->removeRow(/* What goes here? */);
```

Otherwise let me know if I'm completely on the wrong track.

**Update:**

I found and modified some code that allows to me to delete the row if the entire row's contents are selected:

```
QModelIndexList indexes = ui->tvStock->selectionModel()->selectedRows();

while (!indexes.isEmpty()) {
    stockModel->removeRows(indexes.last().row(), 1);
    indexes.removeLast();
}
```

Is there a way this code could be modified to delete the entire row if only one of the row items is selected?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012450/qt-delete-selected-row-in-qtableview

Comment: The link to that question doesn't solve my problem of how to identify the index of the QTableView.

Comment: Call `selectedIndexes` from the view and pass the row number into `removeRow`. The logic used for figuring out which rows to remove in case of different indices selected (for example, if you're allowing single multiple cells to be selected) is up to you.

Comment: Or, even better, call `selectionModel` on the view and then call `selectedRows` on the returned object. This will give you a list of `QModelIndex` objects representing unique selected rows that you can just loop over and pass the row number directly into `removeRow`.